# How get Notification when user at home or in office

Tags: android, notifications, gps

I am New in android, I am going to develop a small app in which user get notification of "Welcome to Office" if his location is of his office and also same for his home if his location is his home. Please tell me what should i have to do to do that.

Comment: Search "Geofencing android" on google.

Comment: @FlamePrincess this is what I was looking for.
Do you have some examples of it so i can refer them and learn about it.

Comment: Thank you @FlamePrincessϡ i get good hint from your comment.
I also get respected program code.
I don't know about "Geofencing" but it looks very useful and important, can you tell me about it little bit.
Here is link which is helpful to me..

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-proximity-alerts-tutorial.html

Comment: Yes, its what you want. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;

import com.gs.mobile.Constants;
import com.gs.mobile.R;

public class MyLocation {
    private Timer timer1;
    private LocationManager lm;
    private LocationResult locationResult;
    private boolean gps_enabled=false;
    private boolean network_enabled=false;
    private AlertDialog.Builder dialog;

    public boolean getLocation(final Context context, LocationResult result){
        //I use LocationResult callback class to pass location value from MyLocation to user code.
        locationResult=result;
        if(lm==null)
            lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        //exceptions will be thrown if provider is not permitted.
        try{gps_enabled=lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);}catch(Exception ex){}
        try{network_enabled=lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);}catch(Exception ex){}

        //don't start listeners if no provider is enabled
        if(!gps_enabled && !network_enabled){
            dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            dialog.setMessage(context.getResources().getString(R.string.gps_network_not_enabled));

            dialog.show();

        }
         if(gps_enabled)
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerGps);
        if(network_enabled)
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerNetwork);
        timer1=new Timer();
        timer1.schedule(new GetLastLocation(), 20000);
        return true;
    }

    LocationListener locationListenerGps = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            timer1.cancel();
            locationResult.gotLocation(location);
            lm.removeUpdates(this);
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    };

    LocationListener locationListenerNetwork = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            timer1.cancel();
            locationResult.gotLocation(location);
            lm.removeUpdates(this);
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    };

    class GetLastLocation extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
             lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
             lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);

             Location net_loc=null, gps_loc=null;
             if(gps_enabled)
                 gps_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
             if(network_enabled)
                 net_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

             //if there are both values use the latest one
             if(gps_loc!=null && net_loc!=null){
                 if(gps_loc.getTime()>net_loc.getTime())
                     locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
                 else
                     locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
                 return;
             }

             if(gps_loc!=null){
                 locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
                 return;
             }
             if(net_loc!=null){
                 locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
                 return;
             }
             locationResult.gotLocation(null);
        }
    }

    public static abstract class LocationResult{
        public abstract void gotLocation(Location location);
    }
}//MyLocation-class
```

Calling this from an activity is as shown below

```
/* Used to Get Device GPS Location
     * <uses-permission android:name=�android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION�>
     */
    public static LocationResult locationResult = new LocationResult(){

        @Override
        public void gotLocation(Location location) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };

    public static void getGPS(Activity _activity){
        MyLocation myLocation = new MyLocation();
        myLocation.getLocation(_activity, locationResult);

    }//getGPS()

    public static void getGPS(Activity _activity,LocationResult locationResult){
        MyLocation myLocation = new MyLocation();
        myLocation.getLocation(_activity, locationResult);

    }//getGPS()
```

every time when the lat and lang changed Your  public void gotLocation(Location location) method will be called where you can check whether the location comes under you expected or not.

If you want, even you can make use of the URL http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=37.4188514,-122.0874526&sensor=true

where you can get the name of that lat,lang by sending to this google service.

Comment: this logic consume more battery, because u r get every time current lat and lang

Comment: @user3585230 Yes you're right, but that's how you do it without using external sensors. Or else you can use wifi connectivity using router's mac address or another better way is using iBeacons.

Answer (score 2):

**Create geofence**
geofence work perfectly when user enter this area and exit area.
give unique id for pending intent.

Answer (score 0):

For doing this you should use `GPS` you have to set notification with respect to location. But Make sure you sholud give option to user to save there location for ofice and home or anything else you want to save

Hope it will help you

Comment: Yes @Sukhwant i get that, but want to know that is it necessary to use Service in such program? because whole program is doing his work in background.